# Opencv video frames. I can see only last frame

Tags: c++, opencv, video, timer

I would like save video in array of frames. 
My video have 250 frames. I trying save video:

```
Mat array[250];
Mat frame;
VideoCapture inputVideo(filename);
int index=0;
while(inputVideo.read(frame))
{
array[index] = frame;
index++;
}
```

But this doesn`t work.
Then i trying play my video within timer, i can see only last frame of video. 
Any element of array[250] contain last frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get desired result by

```
Mat array[250];
VideoCapture inputVideo(filename);
int index=0;
while(inputVideo.read( array[index] ))
{
index++;
}
```

or

```
Mat array[250];
Mat frame;
VideoCapture inputVideo(filename);
int index=0;
while(inputVideo.read(frame))
{
array[index] = frame.clone();
index++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Amazing. It very easy.